# How to revert all commits merged from one branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-revert

I've a release branch for example `release/4.0.1` which we used to add all change to this release and merge it to our `QA` branch. We made several commits and made multiple merges to our `QA` branch. Now, we want to remove all changes in `QA` which were made from `release/4.0.1`. There are other merges and commits that were done on the branch.

What is the simplest way to do it ? reverting the changes and commits releated to that branch only.

Comment: Do you have the "merge commit" when you did merge *release/4.0.1* branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's visualize your scenario:

```
o---o---o------o (some-other-branch)
                \
o---o---o---M1---N---M2 (QA)
     \     /        /
      A---B---C----D (release/4.0.1)
```

In order to undo the changes in `QA` that came from commits `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, you need to revert the merge commits `M1` and `M2`.

First, you need to find the merge commits that happened on `QA` after `release/4.0.1` was [forked](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---fork-point):

```sh
git log --format='%h %s' --right-only --merges releases/4.0.1...QA
```

This will return the IDs and commit messages of `M1`, `N` and `M2`<sup>1</sup>. For example:

```sh
18abe3e Merge branch 'release/4.0.1'
2db6c39 Merge branch 'some-other-branch'
b49ea3f Merge branch 'release/4.0.1'
```

At this point, you can revert the merge commits from `release/4.0.1` in `QA` starting from the latest one:

```sh
git switch QA
git revert -m 1 b49ea3f # Reverts M2
git revert -m 1 18abe3e # Reverts M1
```

Alternatively, you can revert all merge commits in a single commit:

```sh
git switch QA
git revert -m 1 --no-commit b49ea3f # Reverts M2
git revert -m 1 --no-commit 18abe3e # Reverts M1
# Verify that everything works
git commit -m "Revert merge commits M2 and M1"
```

A word of caution: reverting a merge commit removes the changes, but it does not alter the history of the branches. This complicates things if you ever wanted to merge `release/4.0.1` into `QA` again. Read the documentation for more information on [the consequences of reverting a merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt).

---

1. Unfortunately, it's not possible to filter out merge commits from other branches that happened *in between*. In this example, `N` happened between `M1` and `M2`, so it's going to make the cut.

Comment: @TTT Thanks. Unfortunately, `N` is indeed going to be in the list, since it happened in between. I updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: OK- that makes sense. Also, I think you want to revert in reverse order?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio you can revert the revert if you want merge it back agian